# Hide real url from third party in PHP

Tags: php, url

I want to hide real URLs from third party file sharing websites like Amazon AWS, Google Drive , Microsoft One Drive,...?

For example:
I have one url like this one

> http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4

Is there anyway to make the URL looks like this?

> http://myhosting.com/example.php?filename=oceans.mp4

Comment: yes, all you'd be doing is proxying the request for the file, which means you double your bandwidth bill: download the file from the 3rd party, then uploading to the user.

Comment: mabye store that file name in a database with the real url and when you go to your url with that file name, it'll look up the real url in the database